# Did Russia help India arm itself with nuclear weapons?

Tags: india, russia, nuclear

Although Canada provided India with its first nuclear reactor [ccnr](http://www.ccnr.org/exports_3.html), much of the fuel for India's reactors have come from Russia [India Times](http://expressindia.indianexpress.com/news/fullstory.php?newsid=65381).  India asserts that the atomic weapons program was entirely [indigenous](http://nuclearweaponarchive.org/India/IndiaWDevelop.html).

Despite that assertion, the original poster and many others believe that India's nuclear weapons program was assisted by Russia.   For the purposes of this question, assume that the Soviet Union *did* assist India's nuclear weapons program.

Why?
What Soviet national interests would have been advanced by the assistance?

Please answer with research, short of book length, without reference to counterfactuals.

Comment: Where did you gather this from? India's weapon development seems to be mostly done at home (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smiling_Buddha).

Comment: @MonsterTruck That article does acknowledge Russian help.

Comment: "From what I gathered...." Since this seems to have created controversy, perhaps you could cite the research that led you to this conclusion.

Comment: @LennartRegebro Is this when Indian scientists toured a Russian facility?

Comment: @LennartRegebro the USSR and later Russia sold military equipment to India and accepted Indians into their universities, they did not sell of give away nuclear weapons as is claimed.

Comment: @jwenting Well, yes, you are right, I was just giving Surya the benefit of the doubt. But now there is an answer that answers the question given, so the question can't really be improved without invalidating the answer.

Comment: I have recast the question as a yes-no question that can now be answered factually. Can it now be re-opened?

Comment: @TomAu - the title is edited, but the question is still flawed. The text of the question is "[Why](http://meta.history.stackexchange.com/a/689/1401)", based on a potentially flawed assumption; I think these flaws are likely to lead to continued discussion rather than an answer.

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace: You have helped me with edits before. Perhaps you can finish the job I started.

Answer (score 9):

The military relations between India and Russia is based on "India's needs and Russia's opportunism".
India needs technology and Russia provides it, by selling it. By this Russia gets lot of money, a friend and balance against West(until cold war) and a counterweight to threats from China and Islamist fundamentalits. The new relation(post cold war) is primarily of business interest.

SOURCE (very interesting read): [INDO-RUSSIAN MILITARY AND NUCLEAR COOPERATION: IMPLICATIONS FOR U.S. SECURITY INTERESTS](http://www.fas.org/nuke/guide/india/doctrine/ocp31.htm)

---

There is certainly a very [thin line between civilian nuclear program and nuclear weapons program](http://www.nytimes.com/2007/12/05/world/middleeast/05weapons.html?_r=0) and most of the times we confuse them with each other.
India has indeed benefited from various nations in her civilian nuclear program which includes US, Canada, France etc. Russia too fits, equally, into this list.

But India has not taken any direct help for her nuclear weapons program from any nation. And, [Indo-US nuclear deal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/U.S.%E2%80%93India_Civil_Nuclear_Agreement) is a proof of this. India is the only nation who have not signed [NPT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treaty_on_the_Non-Proliferation_of_Nuclear_Weapons) and [CTBT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comprehensive_Nuclear-Test-Ban_Treaty) and still major powers are willing to make nuclear agreements with India and is getting [NSG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_Suppliers_Group) waivers. If India had proliferated its nuclear weapons technology no such things were possible.

Russia did **not** arm India with nuclear weapons. It was India who armed herself with nuclear weapons as a deterrence to her unfriendly neighbors particularly China. However, India had significantly taken advantage of technology and equipment and nuclear fuel given by other nations for her civilian nuclear program to develop nuclear weapons.

---

It is a recent (Jan,2003) CIA mid-term report that claims:

> Russia has significantly supported in developing India’s nuclear
>   programmes with technology and equipment, and become a main source of
>   arms for the country.

Here the 'nuclear program' is civilian nuclear program and 'arms' are non-nuclear arms like tanks, planes and other military hardware.

It also states that this technology and equipment was given to China and Iran too.

The main motivation for this help, as CIA report claims:

> Russia’s cash-strapped defence, biotechnology, chemical, aerospace and
>   nuclear industries, **are eager to raise funds via exports and transfers.**

for this funds,

> Russian President Vladimir Putin in May 2000 amended the
>   presidential decree on nuclear exports to allow Russia to export
>   nuclear materials, technology and equipment to countries that do not
>   have full-scope IAEA safeguards.

So, it is not Russia who is arming India. But its India, who is arming herself as a necessity for national security.

**SOURCES:**

1. CIA reports: [1. the Dawn](http://archives.dawn.com/2003/01/10/top5.htm)  and  [2. express india](http://expressindia.indianexpress.com/news/fullstory.php?newsid=18265)
2. [Sublette, Carey. "Origins of Indian nuclear program"](http://nuclearweaponarchive.org/India/IndiaOrigin.html)
3. [JFK's Overshadowed Crisis](http://nationalinterest.org/article/jfks-overshadowed-crisis-7073?page=show)